# SSIS Execute Process Task Hangs

Tags: sql, cmd, ssis

I have an SSIS package that uses the Execute Process Task to run an application. Running on my local visual studio has no issues. Running it on the server as a job, from the logs, I can see that it just hangs on the EPT step. It never errors or stops.

The old version of the application runs from the same directory as part of a job on a server with no issue. I'm simply just running a new version of the application. It does pass arguments slightly different though.

I log into the server as the SQL Agent service account and run the executable commands from CMD the same as the SSIS package runs it, and it runs fine.

The task is configured with default configurations except for the window is hidden, the same as the old version that works.

I've seen many people have this issue and have tried everything..

I'm assuming that it's prompting me something when it runs on the server. Is there any way to see what it's prompting if I am logged into the server running the job?

Comment: I would try using an output redirect `>` e.g. `myapp.exe Arg1 Arg2 > C:\temp\what_happened.txt` and see if anything shows up in there.

Comment: not sure I follow exactly but i have gone into the app on the server, and told it essentially to do the same thing as what my CMD's are telling it to do, and it works without issue. I have also ran a CMD prompt C:\application arg 1 arg 2, and it runs without any prompting/issue on the server.

Comment: I did the output to a text file and it shows it doing exactly as expected. Its the same message provided in the CMD prompt after running it.

Comment: How about this as a test, SQL Agent Job, type of OS command and call myapp.exe. Ensure the same account that you use to execute SSIS packages runs the same process. Does it work? If not, my theory is that there is some desktop interactivity that is denied to the account that does not apply to a normal account

Comment: The job fails instantly saying it can't find the file. It's run by the same account that I log into the server with and run the same exact command without issue on the server. Odd. I am almost positive the core issue is because the application is prompting for a user name and PW even though I passed it on through the SSIS. I noticed that on the first run (cache much be clearing), even though I am passing user name and PW, it still asks for it.

Comment: Check sql agent service is executed by which user and give access to it on executable folder and file . It will mostly be nt\system or something like that.